# How do i fine-tune Hex-Rays decompiler for 16-bit?

Tags: decompile

It is mentioned on the IDA Pro Hex-Rays site under decompiler error messages

> **16-bit functions are not supported**

It goes on to say:

> The decompiler itself CAN be fine tuned to decompile 16-bit code, 
>   however this is not a priority for now.

Does anyone know how to "fine-tune" the decompiler in this way?

Answer (score 2):

That is meant to say that the developers at Hex-Rays can fine tune the decompiler code to work on 16-bit code, but it is not a priority for them right now.

It would be non-trivial for an end-user without the decompiler's source code to fine-tune the decompiler plugin. But, if you feel you're up for the challenge, go for it! :)