# In theory, Hex-Rays CAN Decompile 16-bit code. But how?

Tags: decompile

A while back i e-mailed Hex-Rays about decompiling (obtaining pseudocode) from 16-bit functions ( 16bit code ). They replied in theory it can be done. Others have succeded,
but Hex-Rays themselves have never tried it. Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i fine-tune Hex-Rays decompiler for 16-bit?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/how-do-i-fine-tune-hex-rays-decompiler-for-16-bit)

Comment: I don't think you understood the reply correctly.

Comment: To expand: to enable 16-bit support, the decompiler's *source code* needs to be modified, and even then most of it will not work properly (yes, we did try it). There is no hidden setting in the released plugin that magically enables 16-bit decompilation. As far as I'm aware, there are no "others" who "have succeeded" in using Hex-Rays for 16-bit decompilation. (If you have proof to the contrary, please provide it.)